# IntelliJ Run button disabled trying to run an Appium/Maven project

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, appium

I'm new to automating tests for mobile apps, and in my work they use Eclipse with Appium and Maven plugins, but I find myself more comfortable IntelliJ. I've already set everything to work with it but when I write some of my code and try to run the test, the run Button is disabled.

I've searched on Google and tried all the anwsers but nothing seems to work. My java directory is set to Sources root, my test folder is also set as Test root, I I think the problem is in my configurations, because in "Android App" no module is set, but even though my project is set as a module, I do not know why I can't choose it in the Edit Configurations window. 
I'll put the screenshots, hope you guys can help me, Thanks!

Here are the links to my screenshots, I just made my account and can't post images yet...

[A general view of the IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7aSk.png)

[Edit Configuration Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kx3P1.png)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any Run/Debug configurations, hence you can't run anything and the buttons are disabled.

What you see in the dialog is the list of the **Default** configurations.

You need to [add a new configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html#createExplicitly) first by clicking on the <kbd>**`[+]`**</kbd> button.